# Replace a word in a string with powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, join, split

I'm trying to replace the word `of` in a string, with a PowerShell script.

I have tried an if statement:

```
$string = "a tale of two cities "   

$array = $string -split " "    

if($array -match 'of') {
    $array -replace 'bob'
}
```

The statement works at detecting `of` but I don't know how to replace it with a different word.

Comment: You should always check the documentation, and maybe a few web pages about the command(s) you're having trouble with. For this problem, I would suggest you look at [`Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) and [this Scripting Guy column](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/21/use-powershell-to-replace-text-in-strings/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single expression using the `-replace` operator is all you need:

```
> 'a tale of two cities' -replace '\bof\b', 'bob'
a tale bob two cities
```

If you want the resulting string split into words by whitespace:

```
$array = -split 'a tale of two cities' -replace '\bof\b', 'bob'
```

Comment: would it be posable to have the world to be replaced like "of" be in an array and test the array for a list of words? Like:             $array = $array -replace $wordList

Comment: @williamyocom: No, `-replace` only supports a single string on the RHS. I suggest you ask a _new_ question (feel free to let me know here once you've done so).

Answer (score 0):

I find the method version a bit simpler:

```
"a tale of two cities ".Replace('of','bob')
```

Or even:

```
$string = "a tale of two cities "
$string.Replace('of','bob')
```

Comment: Yes, in this particular case the _literal_  replacement that the `.Replace()` _method_ of the `[string]` .NET class performs is simpler, but in general PowerShell's _regex_-based `-replace` _operator_ is more flexible.